# Left join SQL Server return result based on ranking

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a one to many left join in SQL Server 2008 and need to return a row based on a priority assigned in the query.   For the sake of clarity, assume that A is the most important, followed by B, C...

In my table these varchar fields are words, and cannot be ordered alphabetically, and so (I think) I need to assign a numerical value to each.

```
Table1
Station 1
Station 2
Station 3


Table2 
Station 1   User 1  A
Station 1   User 2  B
Station 1   User 3  A
Station 1   User 4  B
Station 1   User 5  B
Station 2   User 1  B
Station 2   User 2  F
Station 2   User 3  D
Station 2   User 4  S
Station 2   User 5  E
Station 3   User 1  D
Station 3   User 2  D
Station 3   User 3  D
Station 3   User 4  S
Station 3   User 5  C
```

I'd like to return the results below:

```
Station 1   A
Station 2   B
Station 3   C
```

Ie A is the most important for station 1, B for Station 2 etc.

My logic so far is to use a case, min and select in statement:

```
select t1.station
, min(
case 
    when A then 1
    when B then 2
    when C then 3
    when D then 4
end
)
from table1.t1 left join table2.t2 on t1.station = t2.station
group by t1.station
```

However, since I'm returning multiple lines with the join, I'm not sure how to deal with this, I also wish to return the string, not the priority assigned.  I'd appreciate some help on this, Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume there's more to this, as you do not need a join with the details you have supplied: `select station, min(...) from t2 group by station;`

Comment: @Phylogenesis, yes I trimmed it down to (try and) give some clarity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY` clause of a [**`ROW_NUMBER`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function:

```
select station, mycol
from (
   select t1.station, t2.mycol,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.station
                             ORDER BY CASE t2.mycol
                                        WHEN A THEN 1
                                        WHEN B THEN 2
                                        WHEN C THEN 3
                                        WHEN D THEN 4
                                      end) AS rn
   from table1.t1 
   left join table2.t2 on t1.station = t2.station) as t
where t.rn = 1
```

The query will pick the record having the greatest priority within each `t1.station` partition. It also returns the other field from `table2`.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response, I think it misses t2.mycol between 'case when', but this has definitely set me on the right track- much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to do is use Row_Number() function in order to rank your order.  Let me know if you have any questions:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx